# Laravel, how to display Values in DB with just given IDs?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

im trying to get 5 data from DB with their ID ?

HTML

```
<input type="number" name="cid1">
<input type="number" name="cid2">
<input type="number" name="cid3">
<input type="number" name="cid4">
<input type="number" name="cid5">
```

Route

```
Route::post('/selectCampaign','EmailController@selectCampaign')->name('selectCampaign');
```

Controller - im Trying to get Just 1 ID and its not Working

```
public function selectCampaign(Request $request) 
    {
        $id1 = request('cid1');
        
        $offers = Offer::where('id','=', $id1);
        return view('email_add', compact('offers'));
    }
```

I want to show 5 Offers from Offers Table, with given 5 ID in HTML Form ? How can i do this in Laravel ?

Comment: Well right away I see you're not executing your query. You need to call `get()` or `first()` etc in order to fetch the results. Right now `$offers` still contains the query builder object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never execute your query... `where()` is a Query Builder instance, until you call `->first()` or `->get()`. If you want 1 record, then use `first()`, if you want multiple, then use `get()`.

Or, in your case, you can use `find()`:

```php
$offer = Offer::where('id', '=', $request->input('cid1'))->first();
// OR
$offer = Offer::find($request->input('cid1'));
```

If you want to get all 5, then you'd call:

```php
$offers = Offer::whereIn('id', [
  $request->input('cid1'),
  $request->input('cid2'),
  $request->input('cid3'),
  $request->input('cid4'),
  $request->input('cid5')
])->get();
```

Or, if no other input is being passed from your form:

```php
$offers = Offer::whereIn('id', $request->except('_token'))->get();
```